# set the alignment of the data segment in TASM ideal mode

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, tasm

My assembly source code:

```
ideal 
model tiny 
segment _data byte  ; TASM doesn't accept it. 
ends _data 
 
dataseg 
align 1  ; Doesn't decrease the segment alignment. 
lpText  db "Hello, world!$" 
 
codeseg 
        startupcode 
        lea dx,[lpText] 
        mov ah,9 
        int 21h 
        exitcode 
end
```

TASM 5.0 gives me the error *Segment attributes illegally redefined* for the line with `byte` in it.

How do I change the data segment to byte alignment in ideal mode?

I need it because I don't want an extra 0 byte in the generated .com file in front of *lpText*. I want the .com file to be as small as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to reopen a segment like `_DATA` then the segment must match the previously declared segment attributes. When you use the simplified DOS segments and the `model` directive the default is WORD alignment for the `_TEXT` and `_DATA` segments. You have changed the alignment from the default of WORD to BYTE and thus are getting the error you see. The [TASM 5 manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf) states:

> **Segment attributes illegally redefined**
>
> A SEGMENT directive reopen a segment that has been previously defined,
> and tries to give it different attributes. For example:
>
> ```
> DATA SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC
> DATA ENDS
> DATA SEGMENT PARA                 ; error, previously had byte alignment
> DATA ENDS
> ```
>
> **If you reopen a segment, the attributes you supply must either match
> exactly or be omitted entirely.** If you don't supply any attributes
> when reopening a segment, the old attributes will be used.

---

You have a couple of choices. One is the simpler one and that is to combine the code and data in the code segment:

```
ideal
model tiny

codeseg
        startupcode
        lea dx,[lpText]
        mov ah,9
        int 21h
        exitcode
lpText:  db "Hello, world!$"

end
```

If you were to assemble this it should generate a program with a **size of 25 bytes**:

> ```
> 00000100  BA0B01            mov dx,0x10b
> 00000103  B409              mov ah,0x9
> 00000105  CD21              int 0x21
> 00000107  B44C              mov ah,0x4c
> 00000109  CD21              int 0x21
> 0000010B  48                dec ax
> 0000010C  656C              gs insb
> 0000010E  6C                insb
> 0000010F  6F                outsw
> 00000110  2C20              sub al,0x20
> 00000112  776F              ja 0x183
> 00000114  726C              jc 0x182
> 00000116  642124            and [fs:si],sp
> ```

---

An alternative is to not use the `model` directive and declare your own segments from scratch:

```
ideal
group DGROUP _DATA, _TEXT

segment _TEXT byte 'CODE'
org 100h
ends
segment _DATA byte 'DATA'
ends

segment _DATA
lpText  db "Hello, world!$"
ends

segment _TEXT
_start:
    lea dx,[lpText]            ; or mov dx, offset lptext
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ret                        ; COM programs that use TINY model
                               ; can exit with a RET. DOS places 0000h
                               ; on the stack when program starts. Returning
                               ; to 0000h executes an INT 20h instruction at
                               ; offset 0000h in the PSP
ends

end _start
```

The `startupcode` and `exitcode` directives don't work outside the simplified segment model so you need to generate the code yourself. Since I am assuming you are using `tiny` model to generate DOS COM programs you can use `ret` to return from DOS assuming you don't need to return an error level. This reduces the size of the program. There is no need to set the segment registers as CS=DS=ES=SS are all pointing at the [Program Segment Prefix (PSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) when DOS starts running the COM program. The program generated would look like this:

> ```
> 00000100  BA0801            mov dx,0x108
> 00000103  B409              mov ah,0x9
> 00000105  CD21              int 0x21
> 00000107  C3                ret
> 00000108  48                dec ax
> 00000109  656C              gs insb
> 0000010B  6C                insb
> 0000010C  6F                outsw
> 0000010D  2C20              sub al,0x20
> 0000010F  776F              ja 0x180
> 00000111  726C              jc 0x17f
> 00000113  642124            and [fs:si],sp
> ```

The resulting COM program should be a **size of 22 bytes**.

---

If you had replaced `ret` in the previous code with:

```
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

The resulting file would be a **size of 25 bytes** and more importantly the `_DATA` segment is not aligned on a WORD boundary:

> ```
> 00000100  BA0B01            mov dx,0x10b
> 00000103  B409              mov ah,0x9
> 00000105  CD21              int 0x21
> 00000107  B44C              mov ah,0x4c
> 00000109  CD21              int 0x21
> 0000010B  48                dec ax
> 0000010C  656C              gs insb
> 0000010E  6C                insb
> 0000010F  6F                outsw
> 00000110  2C20              sub al,0x20
> 00000112  776F              ja 0x183
> 00000114  726C              jc 0x182
> 00000116  642124            and [fs:si],sp
> ```

Comment: Thank you for providing all the details of these options. My TL;DR is that when using a `model` in TASM, it's impossible to change the segment alignment.